# Is there a way to evaluate this integral without power series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to evaluate 
$$ \int \frac{\arctan(x)}{x} dx $$
One way of doing it is to use power-series. I can re-write 
$$ \arctan(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1} }{2n+1} \ \ |x|<1 $$

$$ \int \frac{\arctan(x)}{x} dx = \int \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n} }{2n+1} dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1} }{(2n+1)^2} + C$$

But now I am curious whether there is any **other way** to evaluate this integral?

Comment: Not really. Depending on what you consider a reasonable answer, it's possible to integrate by parts and split the resulting integral of shape $\ln(x)/(1 + x^2)$ into to logarithmic-type integrals (with an imaginary component from writing $x^2 + 1 = (x + i)(x - i)$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there isn't really a nice way to do this other than writing your integral in terms of [dilogarithms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html). But you may be interested to know that this is a well known integral, called the [inverse tangent integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangentIntegral.html), and it was studied heavily by [Ramanujan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan).